# Не работает загрузка данных через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Добрый день! У меня возникла такая проблема при разработке сайта. Использую CMS разработанной в одной из веб-студии, которой нет в сети, она самописная. Суть в двух словах такая, есть исполняемый файл index.php, и через него все обрабатывается, тоесть нет каких-то переходов на другие страницы. Служебные файлы и классы находятся в подпапке, которые подключены к index.php. Так вот делая админку для сайта, а это как бы виртуальная папка url-сайта корневой/admin/goods/№номер товара. Вот в общем делаю ajax запрос, где к товару (услуге) должна подключаться галлерея картинок. Пишу так примерно:

```
function Createtable_(ID)
 {
    $.ajax(
    {type: 'POST', 
     url: 'select_ajax.php', 
     data: {good_id:ID},
     success: function(response)
     {
        $('#html-data-table').html(response);
     }
   } 
 );
}
```

Так вот, а в файле select_ajax.php находится сам код формирования данных, которые потом возвращаются таблице table с id=html-data-table. Но только вместо данных я почему-то получаю такую ситуацию, что в таблицу грузится страница опять же... Тоесть как фрейм работает... Не знаю даже как это исправить, странное поведение. Подскажите кто-нибудь?

Comment: > Но только вместо данных я почему-то получаю такую ситуацию, что в таблицу грузится страница опять же... Тоесть как фрейм работает... Не знаю даже как это исправить, странное поведение. Подскажите кто-нибудь?

Вам нужно данные в json получить или готовый html в элемент загрузить?

Comment: проблема в том, что при обращении через index.php CMS отдает весь шаблон. Попробуйте свои данные выводить через echo, а после вывода делать exit().
Второй вариант - разрешить обращение к своему php-файлу напрямую и в ajax-запросе обращаться к нему напрямую. Покажите настройки, по которым выполняется редирект на index.php (в случае с Apache это файл .htaccess), придумаем, как туда исключение для вашего скрипта добавить.
Еще один вариант, разобраться, как в CMS выполянется частичный рендеринг страницы (без основного шаблона)

Comment: @Fike, я в файле select_ajax.php формирую html-код (а именно теги таблицы html-data-table), потом вывожу их на экран, а там внутри таблицы, выводится еще одна страница 404. @vanchester, да согласен с тобой, что надо в этом направлении двигаться... 
Мой .htaccess содержит следующее:

    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    
    Options +Followsymlinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /404/
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule    (.*)$  index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
    
    php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из этого
    **url: 'select_ajax.php'**
предполагается что файл select_ajax.php находится в корне сайта, но если его нет (а он у Вас находится в субдиректории) то естественно происходит вызов index.php,

попробуйте прописать путь к указанному файлу  **url: './puth/select_ajax.php'**

Comment: Прописывайте полный путь к файлу ('http://site.com/select_ajax.php/),

Comment: @Victor Halauko
1. Если относительный путь А разрешается в абсолютный путь Б, то они эквивалентны в использовании
2. Ваш пример ссылается на несуществующую директорию

Comment: Я исправил опечатку